# How to import two jni module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        moduleName "p7zip"
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
    }
    ndk {
        moduleName "CryptUtils-jni"
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
```

}

It give me the error message " Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load CryptUtils-jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.pncmicros.banksia.mediaplayer.client-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.pncmicros.banksia.mediaplayer.client-2]: findLibrary returned null                                                                                         "
And I jni folder like below:

[image]

Android.mk file write like this:

```
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

Android.mk in folder "CryptUtils" 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9927654/CryptUtils-Android.mk

[image]

Android.mk in folder "p7zip"
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9927654/p7zip-Android.mk

[image]

[image]